# Persist presenter with dagger in activity

Tags: java, android

How do you keep the presenter alive within an activity when you inject a presenter to it with an activity scope on rotation?

My understanding is that the presenter and activity is destroyed and a new presenter and activity is created every time. Is there a way to keep the presenter alive while the activity gets recreated?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, providing that we are talking about configuration changes (e.g. rotation).

You can override FragmentActivity's method

`fun onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance():Any` 
 - to save your presenter on rotation.

To restore the same instance during onCreate() 
just call
`getLastCustomNonConfigurationInstance():Any`

[Here](https://github.com/partition/Dagger-Non-Configuration-Scope/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/github/partition/nonconfscope/BaseActivity.java) is example with saving Dagger 2 subcomponent in BaseActivity. When you use approach to save dagger's component instead of just presenter, creation of presenters becomes super easy:

- mark prestenter constructor with `@Inject`
- mark presenter field in your target activity with `@Inject`
- get injector from BaseActivity (as in linked class) and inject it during onCreate in target activity.